# How to cheaply process large amounts of data (local setup or cloud)?

Tags: heroku, nlp, cloud, scaling, bigdata

I would like to try testing NLP tools against dumps of the web and other corpora, sometimes larger than 4 TB.

If I run this on a mac it's very slow. What is the best way to speed up this process?

- deploying to EC2/Heroku and scaling up servers
- buying hardware and creating a local setup

Just want to know how this is usually done (processing terabytes in a matter of minutes/seconds), if it's cheaper/better to experiment with this in the cloud, or do I need my own hardware setup?

Comment: I guess I should add that I'm running pandora on my computer too (sometimes netflix as well), which uses up a lot of memory.

Comment: http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/images/0/0a/XGridHadoopFeb2011.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends quite a bit on what kind of experimenting you are wanting to do, for what purpose and for how long.

If you're looking into buying the hardware and running your own cluster then you probably want something like Hadoop or Storm to manage the compute nodes. I don't know how feasible it is to go through 4TB of data in a matter of seconds but again that really depends on the kind of processing you want to do. Counting the frequency of words in the 4TB corpus should be pretty easy (even or your mac), but building SVMs or doing something like LDA on the lot won't be. One issue you'll run into is that you won't have enough memory to fit all of that, so you'll want a library that can run the methods off disk.

If you don't know exactly what your requirements are then I would use EC2 to setup a test rig to gain a better understanding what it is that you want to do and how much grunt/memory that needs to get done in the amount of time you require.

We recently bought two compute nodes 128 cores each with 256Gb of memory and a few terabytes of disk space for I think it was around £20k or so. These are AMD interlagos machines. That said the compute cluster already had infiniband storage so we just had to hook up to that and just buy to two compute nodes, not the whole infrastructure.

The obvious thing to do here is to start off with a smaller data set, say a few gigabytes. That'll get you started on your mac, you can experiment with the data and different methods to get an idea of what works and what doesn't, and then move your pipeline to the cloud, and run it with more data. If you don't want to start the experimentation with a single sample, you can always take multiple samples from different parts of the full corpus, just keep the sample sizes down to something you can manage on your own workstation to start off with.

As an aside, I highly recommend the [scikit-learn](http://github.com/scikit-learn) project on GitHub for machine learning. It's written in Python, but most of the matrix operations are done in Fortran or C libraries so it's pretty fast. The developer community is also extremely active on the project. Another good library that perhaps a bit more approachable (depending on your level of expertise) is [NLTK](http://nltk.org/). It's nowhere near as fast but makes a bit more sense if you're not familiar with thinking about everything as a matrix.

**UPDATE**

One thing I forgot to mention is the time your project will be running. Or to put it another way, how long will you get some use out of your specialty hardware. If it's a project that is supposed to serve the EU parliament for the next 10 years, then you should definitely buy the hardware. If it's a project for you to get familiar with NLP, then forking out the money might be a bit redundant, unless you're also planning on starting you own cloud computing rental service :).

That said, I don't know what the real world costs of using EC2 are for something like this. I've never had to use them.

Comment: Super helpful notes! And thanks for the link to [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn), looks very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the brand of your cloud, the whole idea of cloud computing is to be able to scale-up and scale down in a flexible way.

In a corporate environment you might have a scenario in which you will consistently need the same amount of computing resources, so if you already have them, it is rather a difficult case to use the cloud because you just don't need the flexibility provided.

On the other hand if your processing tasks are not quite predictable, your best solution is the cloud because you will be able to pay more when you use more computing power, and then pay less when you don't need as much power.

Take into account though, that not all cloud-solutions are the same, for instance, a Web role is a highly web-dedicated node whose main purpose is to serve web requests, the more requests are served, the more you pay.

Whereas in a virtual role, is almost like you are given the exclusivity of a computer system that you can use for anything you want, either a linux or a windows OS, the system keeps running even though you are not using it at its best.

Overall, the costs depend on your own scenario and how well it fits to your needs.

Comment: I don't get the relevance of the Web role / virtual role. That applies to web hosting not to cloud computing services where you pay for what you use.

Comment: thanks for the refinement in my comment :) ... I wanted to state the dilemma you have when you are choosing a type of role in Windows Azure for example, you may have the option to take a WebRole which is primarly a node with IIS installed but that you cannot use the filesystem, and others such as Virtual Role, when you have a fresh install and can be used for all-purposes. Of course, both of them have different costs.  Does that make sense for you?